# Different output of command substitution

Tags: bash, process

Why does adding `| wc -l` alters the result as in the following?

**tst:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
pgrep tst | wc -l
echo $(pgrep tst | wc -l)
echo $(pgrep tst) | wc -l
```

```
$ ./tst
1
2
1
```

and even

```
$ bash -x tst
+ wc -l
+ pgrep tst
0
++ pgrep tst
++ wc -l
+ echo 0
0
++ pgrep tst
+ echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgrep` and subshells can have weird interactions, but in this case that's just a red herring; the actual cause is missing double-quotes around the command substitution:

```
$ cat tst2
#!/bin/bash
pgrep tst | wc -l
echo "$(pgrep tst | wc -l)"
echo "$(pgrep tst)" | wc -l
$ ./tst2
1
2
2
```

What's going on in the original script is that in the command

```
echo $(pgrep tst) | wc -l
```

`pgrep` prints two process IDs (the main shell running the script, and a subshell created to handle the `echo` part of the pipeline). It prints each one as a separate line, something like:

```
11730
11736
```

The command substitution captures that, but since it's not in double-quotes the newline between them gets converted to an argument break, so the whole thing becomes equivalent to:

```
echo 11730 11736 | wc -l
```

As a result, `echo` prints both IDs as a single line, and `wc -l` correctly reports that.

Answer (score 1):

The command substitution induces an additional process that has `tst` in its name, which is included in the input to `wc -l`.

Comment: But why is the third line then just spitting out _one_ PID? I slightly changed the code above to make it more concise.

Comment: Possibly an optimization, as the shell induced by the command substitution sees that it only has to run one command, so it doesn't fork.